# Does SQL Server take into consideration the transformations done on a previous column if it's used to calculate another one?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, temp-tables

Hello I am inserting multiple rows in a table as follows :

1. I created a temp table let's say with 3 column [Column1], [Column2] and [Column3]:

```
Create table #temp AS
SELECT
 [Column1]
,CASE WHEN [Column1]=20 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS [Column2]
,CASE WHEN [Column2]='YES' THEN 'Huray' ELSE 'Boho' END AS [Column3]
FROM STG_Table
```

2. INSERT THEM

```
INSERT Dest_Table
(
Column1
, Column2
, Column3)

SELECT
(Column1
, Column2
, Column3)
FROM #temp
```

Now my question is, when Column3 is calculated in temp will it take the values from STG or the newly calculated value within temp ?

I hope my question is clear

PS: I am a complete noob

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will take the value from `STG_Table`. And that must have a column called `Column2`. You can't reference expressions  defined in the SELECT in other expressions at the same level.

Comment: @MartinSmith but I wanna use it in a stored procedure, if I do an ALTER TABLE  to add the computed columns it'll fail on the 2nd execution. Also my real case has like 10 computed columns each one is dependent on at least 1 previous computed column. I made a SP with many UPDATES but my manager told me each update will scan the entire table think of another solution

Comment: If you need to define chained expressions you need them at different levels, you can do this by chaining common table expressions or by using CROSS APPLY

Comment: Not sure what you want to do.

You can do following:

CASE WHEN [Column1]=20 THEN 'Huray' ELSE 'Boho' END AS [Column3]

Comment: Just put the whole formula without dependency

Comment: @SlavaMurygin, yeah it'll be ugly performance wise  but that should do the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using multilevel nesting CTEs like in a code below, but I still think hard-coded formulas for each column might be faster because of possible use of parallel calculations. In case of CTEs it doesn't make it in parallel. You can try both scenarios in your  environment and tell us which way would be faster.

```
;WITH CTE1 as (SELECT [Column1], [Column2] = IIF([Column1]=20,'YES','NO') FROM STG_Table)
INSERT Dest_Table(Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT *, [Column3] = IIF([Column2]='YES','Huray','Boho') FROM CTE1;
```